# How to calculate width of div using LESS and then use that value mathematically?

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, less

I am developing a site using LESS values and Bootstrap. I simply would like to do the equivalent of jquery's `$("somediv").width() * somevalue` using LESS.

My current CSS looks like this

```
@test-value:        @grid-columns * 10 / 3; 

.grow:hover .social-links-round {
   opacity: 0.2;
   width: @test-value * 1px;
}
/*the above works fine*/

.grow:hover .social-links-row:hover .social-links-round{
   opacity: 0.5;
   width: this-current-value * 2px; /*this is what i need*/
}
```

is this possible?

Comment: Does `calc()` meet your needs?

Comment: css can't "get" the current width. use js/jq instead

Comment: @josh calc() might work. the my only issue is how do i go about calculating the current value of the div's width?

Comment: @knitevision i'm not only using css. I'm using LESS and i know it can calculate values. I'm just wondering if it there is a way to GET current values without the use of jquery or javascript. I haven't had to create a js page to this point and i'm just trying to avoid having to do so.

Comment: `calc()` can work but it's [not universally supported](http://caniuse.com/#feat=calc). Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/w754f78x/

Comment: @SolomonArnett: Less also cannot know the current values without using JS/jQuery. You could maybe try client side compilation of Less but it is not really recommended.

Comment: Agree with @SolomonArnett, LESS output/compile css, so it have all of css's limitation.